# hibernate HQL query that supports multiple databases oracle and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

I have an application that should support oracle and mysql databases.
I will get different configuration for different database.

But i want all HSQL used in the code to be intact.

But i am not able to do so bcoz of below :

I have created a query like below:

```
String SQL_QUERY = "select count(log) from dbtable where created_date='"+ givenDate
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
query.uniqueResult();
```

This works very well in mysql
but not in oracle

because oracle db expects formatting the value of created_date column with

```
to_date(givenDate,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

so i have to change the above query as :

```
String SQL_QUERY = "select count(log) from dbtable where created_date=to_date('"+ givenDate+","yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Can I avoid this multiple query declarations in any way for mysql and oracle ??

Comment: Why don't you use standard query parameters? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Date%29

Answer (score 1):

Create a `java.sql.Date` out of that `String` and pass it to the query; don't embed the conversion in the database.

Better yet, bind the `String` to a `Date` long before it gets to the persistence tier.  Java's an object-oriented language; think in terms of objects.

Comment: thanks for your response..i tried this..but still exception occurs..........java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string..  could you guess what's wrong going here ??

Comment: yeah, your're still using strings.